# Bash command not found (trying to integrate Beyond Compare with Mercurial and using it within Cygwin)

Tags: bash, cygwin, mercurial, hg, beyondcompare

I'm trying to integrate beyond compare with mercurial and I've copy & pasted the necessary lines from the [Using Beyond Compare with Version Control Systems](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs) page for mercurial into my `.hgrc` file located in `C:\cygwin\home\jerickson` (my cygwin home dir)

when I go to issue an `hg bcomp` command within a mercurial repo i get the following

```
/bin/sh: C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe: command not found
```

**what do I need to modify to get this working? (this does work in powershell and cmd)**

for reference, the relevant parts to my `.hgrc` file is below

```
[ui]
username = Jon Erickson
merge = bcomp

[extensions]
extdiff = 

[extdiff]
cmd.bcomp = C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe
opts.bcomp = /ro

[merge-tools]
bcomp.executable = C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe
bcomp.args = $local $other $base $output
bcomp.priority = 1
bcomp.premerge = True
bcomp.gui = True

[tortoisehg]
vdiff = bcomp
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's a spaces issue.

I'd try the `cygpath` utility, get a DOS 8.3 style path ( `-d` flag) for your Beyond Compare utility.  Remember that Cygwin can use windows paths, I'd use it to your advantage in this case.

Answer (score 0):

cygwin does not know what `C:` is and it definitely does not like un-escaped spaces or parenthesises in a path.

Try this path

> /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Beyond\ Compare\ 3/BComp.exe

(hopefully I have gotten my escapes right)

Or try putting it in quotes

> "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/BComp.exe"

Comment: both of these don't produce any errors, but it also doesn't open beyond compare 3... not sure what is going on...